# Finding the probability density for a component from the probability density of a vector

Tags: probability-distributions, vectors

$\vec{X} = X_1 \vec{u}_1 + X_2 \vec{u}_2 + X_3 \vec{u}_3$ is a random vector. Its probability distribution is $P(\vec{X})$. If I want to find the probability density of the third component $P(X_3)$, I simply have to integrate out the two other components $P(X_3) = \int P(\vec{X}) dX_1 dX_2 $.

Is that right ?